# Opening a workbook in a new window and running a macro in that workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to open a new workbook and run a macro in that workbook I get the following error:

```
"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"
```

Randomly it shows this different error as well:

```
"Cannot run the macro 'macro1'. The macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled"
```

The code I am using is:

```
Sub test_open()
Dim appXL As New Excel.Application

appXL.Workbooks.Open "W:\Brett\_Test\Excel\Book3.xlsm", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
appXL.Visible = True
appXL.Run "macro1"

End Sub
```

Macro settings are set to Enable all macros.

It successfully opens the workbook in a new window but throws the errors.

Comment: You might need to `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`, kill Excel active and background processes -- then re-execute the code and see if the macro runs (it might be good to close the workbook before the code ends, plus `appXL.Quit` at the end and/or explicitly `Set appxl = nothing` at the end). Just to see if there are previous application instances which persist after `End sub`. The other thing you might need to check for is protected mode.

Comment: Try `appXL.Run "Book3.xlsm!macro1"`

Comment: Are you running anything else before this?  I was able to run your code without issues.

Comment: @BruceWayne There's nothing else running.

Comment: @dwirony same thing happened with that code.

Comment: @Brett What is `macro1`?

Comment: @dwirony 
`Sub macro1()
Range("A1").Value = "test"
End Sub`

Comment: Replace macro1 with just `msgbox "hi"` to see if it fires...?

Comment: Which workbook should I replace on?

Comment: @Brett Isn't there only one workbook with the macro called "macro1"?

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of Excel rather than running macro1 within the current instance?  I have never tried this but I assume it allows you to run macro1 as a background process and I do not see how you are terminating the new instance of Excel.  I wonder what problems this might introduce.

Comment: There's 2 workbooks. The first workbook opens the second workbook and calls macro1. I will eventually put a code in macro1 to close the workbook when it's finished. This is just a test and I do want to have macro1 running in the backround while test_open is running as well.

Comment: I can manually run two separate macros on two separate workbooks at the same time no problem.

Comment: When I want a second workbook open, I write `Dim Wbk2 As Workbook` `Set Wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(…)`.  This means I have one copy of Excel running which has two workbooks open.  You have two copies of Excel running each with one workbook open.  I have never tried having multiple copies of Excel running and would not try unless I had some very good reason for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to have the Sub in a Module folder instead of "ThisWorkbook" sheet.